# Fetch data on button pressed

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to learn Flutter and I am trying to make a http request as in [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data) example from the official docs, but since I am learning, I wanted to experiment a little bit, and change it, so I added a text field and a button where I can enter the album Id, and instead of getting always the album with Id:1, I am trying to make it so when I enter the id and press the button Get album, to show the album with that particular Id.
Sorry for showing all the code but I thought it might be helpful on what I am trying to do.

Another problem is that this code shows that the data is fetched in `initState` but I tried to create another function that would be called when the button is pressed but it didn't work, because I am not so familiar with the Flutter.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter_app/album.dart';

Future<Album> fetchAlbums() async {
  final response =
      await http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1');
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return Album.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final _controller = TextEditingController();

  Future<Album> futureAlbum;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureAlbum = fetchAlbums();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My App'),
      ),
      body: Container(
          child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Stack(
            alignment: const Alignment(1.0, 1.0),
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                controller: _controller,
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter album ID...'),
              ),
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  _controller.clear();
                },
                child: Icon(Icons.clear),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: null,
            child: Text('Get Album', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                child: FutureBuilder<Album>(
                  future: futureAlbum,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      return Text(snapshot.data.title);
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                    }
                    // By default, show a loading spinner.
                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

And sample data is:

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "quidem molestiae enim"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "sunt qui excepturi placeat culpa"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "omnis laborum odio"
  },
 ]
```

Update:

```dart
// First I modified the Future, not it get an albumId
Future<Album> fetchAlbums(int albumId) async {
  final response =
      await http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/$albumId');
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return Album.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}

// futureAlbum is updated when the button is pressed and not in initState
onGetAlbum() {
  futureAlbum = fetchAlbums(int.parse(_controller.text));
}

// The raised button, instead of null not calls the onGetAlbum() method when is pressed.
  RaisedButton(
    onPressed: () => onGetAlbum(),
    child: Text('Get Album', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
  ),
```

The errors that I get now:

```
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 3266): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 3266): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection   
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 3266): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnectionW/IInputConnectionWrapper( 3266): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnectionW/IInputConnectionWrapper( 3266): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
```

Comment: `final response =
      await http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1');`

You're always passing this URL. that's why you're getting same data. make it dynamic.

Comment: I know that, but in order to achieve that, I have to make several structural changes to the code, which I am not so familiar with.

Comment: make your function dynamic and call from the proper button with albumId

`Future<Album> fetchAlbums(int albumId) async {
  final response =
      await http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/$albumId');
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return Album.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}`

Comment: How can I call it on button tapped and not in initState and pass the albumId?

Comment: The error stacktrace you posted does not tell us what is wrong. Please show us the first few lines of the stacktrace where the error message is.

Comment: @wxker I updated the error stacktrace, the `Get Album` button now appears to be inactive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after almost a day, i fixed my problem and learned a little bit more of dart, my problem was fairly easy but that is how it is when you are a beginner.

The changes that I had to made beside those in the update of the question:

```dart
RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              futureAlbum = fetchAlbums(int.parse(_controller.text));
              if (_controller.text.length > 0) {
                this.setState(() {
                  _controller.clear(); // Clear value
                }); // clear the textField
                FocusScope.of(context)
                    .requestFocus(new FocusNode()); // hide the keyboard
              }
            },
            child: Text('Get Album', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
          ),
```